# How to retrieve elements from sortable into array

Tags: jquery, arrays, twitter, jquery-ui-sortable, parameters

So i have been working in this:(http://jsfiddle.net/2phuW/5/) for the last couple hours.
Could anyone help me out to figure out the following:

1) in the source sortable the abbreviation wat, ura, or mox needs to be shown
2) when the target is filled, :params[:ready] = true
3) when the target is filled the following code updates accordingly

```
   <ul>
  <li><i class="icon-edit"></i> Not ready </li>
  <li><i class="icon-check"></i> Ready </li>
  </ul>
```

4) when the target is filled, :params[:comp] gets the sorted elements of the target as an array: ie-> [:wat,:ura,:mox,:wat,...]

Thanks in advance